# Unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'ListNode' and 'int'

Tags: python, linked-list

I was working on the leetcode prob, add two numbers. My first pass solution was to convert the linked list into numbers, add them and then convert back to a linked list. I know it may not be the best solution but I wanted something to start. Anyways I am running into an issue where I cant perform operation on the value.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2):
        """
        :type l1: ListNode
        :type l2: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """


        mult = 1
        sum = 0
        while l1.val != None:
            sum = sum + l1.val*mult
            mult *= 10
            l1.val = l1.next

        mult = 1
        while l2.val != None:
            sum += l2.val*mult
            mult *= 10
            l2.val = l2.next
```

I am getting error of

> Unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'ListNode' and 'int'

l1.val should be an integer? Why can I not add or multiply it with another integer? Am I missing something?

Comment: What type of value does `l2.val` have after you do `l2.val = l2.next`?

Comment: Or `l1.val = l1.next`. It may be an `int` on the first iteration but not after that.

Comment: "l1.val should be an integer?" but you assigned `l1.val` with `l1.next` which changed `l1.val` into a `ListNode`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your while-loop, you are **updating `l1.val` as the next node.** This is likely the issue, as your **`l1.val` is now a `ListNode`, not a value, starting from the 2nd iteration.**

You can try the below code instead, I have yet to test it out.

```
        mult = 1
        sum = 0
        while l1.val is not None:
            sum += l1.val * mult
            mult *= 10
            l1 = l1.next # l1 references a ListNode while l1.val is a integer

        mult = 1
        while l2.val is not None:
            sum += l2.val*mult
            mult *= 10
            l2 = l2.next
```

*p.s I also prefer the use of either Pandas `isnull()` or in-built `is not None` instead of `!=` operator.*